# Advaned or autofilter on date range from cell data

Tags: excel, vba, date, input, filter

I have a sheet (Sheet1) where column i is a date field.  I want to create a macro that will ask for input of Start date and End date, place those dates in two cells, say i38,i39, then filter using that data in those cells.  Is this possible?

I am new to macros and VB, and cannot figure out how to use cell data in a date based filter.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with:

[image]

running this:

```
Sub FilterDateRange()
    Dim d1 As String, d2 As String, r As Range
    Set r = Range("I1:I26")

    d1 = ">" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter start date", Type:=2)
    d2 = "<" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter start date", Type:=2)

    r.AutoFilter
    r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=d1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=d2

    Range("I38") = Mid(d1, 2)
    Range("I39") = Mid(d2, 2)
End Sub
```

can produce:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To **include** the end points *(not just between the end points)*, use these lines of code:

```
d1 = ">=" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter start date", Type:=2)
d2 = "<=" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter start date", Type:=2)
```

Comment: Awesome, I will try soon.  If this is a huge file, is there a way to select just column i from top to bottom instead of using the range?  And instead of installing the inputs into a cell, is it possible to just use them in the code without recording them?  I forgot how large the actual file is that needs this filter.  And the size varies every month.

Comment: @12fretter  To filter the entire column use this line ***Set r = Range("I:I")*** instead of the posted line............then drop the last two lines of code above the ***End Sub***

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you so much.

Comment: In testing, I realized the END date is not included in the filter.  Can we increment the variable D2 by 1 before it filters?  I don't know the syntax for doing that.  Thanks again.

Comment: @12fretter  No code change needed....in my example, to go up to and **including** *9/1/2017*, just enter *9/2/2017* in the ***InputBox***

Comment: There are dates of 9/2, 9/3 and 9/4 in the column.  When I use 9/2 and 9/4 as the search dates, it returns only 9/2 and 9/3 data.  I tried substituting <= but this doesn't work either.

Comment: @12fretter  to include 9/4, use 9/5 as the end search date.

Comment: I was hoping there would be no thought required for the person running this macro every month.  Any way to use the <= operand?

Comment: @12fretter  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Yep, that's what I tried first.  It still doesn't work.  The odd thing is, no matter which combination I use, the Start date is always in the results but the end date never is.

Comment: @12fretter  That can happen if the dates have "fuzz" in them.  That is they are really date/times and the time part is hidden by formatting.  If you go to the worksheet and touch *Ctrl-tilda*, that is control plus the tilda key you will see if there is any fraction part to the value.